# Date comparison in Laravel 5.8

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I have the date stored in database and current date using Carbon, 
format: MM/DD/YYYY

I want to compare that the date stored in database has passed away as compared to today's date, comparison in Laravel Query Builder to select data!

I'm working in laravel 5.8
Please, suggest solution!

Comment: You should be showing your existing code and explain what needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare it with `now()`:

```php
if ($this->created_at > now()) {
    return 'Date is in the future';
} else {
    return 'Date is in the past';
}
```